# TOP versus SET ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, performance

Is there a difference in performance between `TOP` and `SET ROWCOUNT` or do they just get executed in the same manner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, functionally they are the same thing.  As far as I know there are no significant performance differences between the two.

Just one thing to note is that once you have `set rowcount` this will persist for the life of the connection so make sure you reset it to `0` once you are done with it.

---

#### EDIT (post Martin's comment)

The scope of `SET ROWCOUNT` is for the current procedure only. This includes procedures called by the current procedure. It also includes dynamic SQL executed via `EXEC` or `SP_EXECUTESQL` since they are considered "child" scopes.

Notice that `SET ROWCOUNT` is in a `BEGIN/END` scope, but it extends beyond that.

```
create proc test1
as
begin
    begin
    set rowcount 100
    end
    exec ('select top 101 * from master..spt_values')
end
GO

exec test1
select top 102 * from master..spt_values
```

Result = 100 rows, then 102 rows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863714/sql-rowcount-vs-top - has few other differences listed between these two, incase anyone is interested.

Comment: I don't think the last line is correct. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383761/scope-of-set-rowcount-in-sql/5383991#5383991

Comment: @Richard: I always thought that `BEGIN...END` was simply a compound statement. Never considered it to be defining a scope as well. Maybe the 'global' `BEGIN...END` is a special case when it is used to specify explicitly the beginning and the end of a programming object's body. But even then, I would say, it simply visualises the scope *of a programming object*, not defines its own.

Comment: Anytime you execute dynamic SQL you create a new batch running on it's own connection.  This isn't a good example and Set RowCount will work even if wrapped in Begin and End.

Answer (score 4):

One more note about performance, according to BOL:

> As a part of a SELECT statement, the query optimizer can consider the value of expression in the TOP or FETCH clauses during query optimization. Because SET ROWCOUNT is used outside a statement that executes a query, its value cannot be considered in a query plan.

[Article on BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Meaning there might be actually performance difference in these.