# Scope of "Set rowcount" in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using "Set RowCount" in my Stored Procedures. I have one question, what is the scope of Set RowCount ? Consider the below SPs

```
 CREATE PROC Test
    AS 
        BEGIN

            SET ROWCOUNT 10
            ...........

            SET ROWCOUNT 0

        END


CREATE PROC Test2
AS 
    BEGIN


        ...........

        SET ROWCOUNT 0

    END


CREATE PROC Test3
AS 
    BEGIN

        SET ROWCOUNT 10
        ...........


    END


CREATE PROC Test4
AS 
    BEGIN

        SET ROWCOUNT 10
        SET ROWCOUNT 5
        ...........
        SET ROWCOUNT 0      

    END
```

Now in the above SPs, you must be seeing I have mismatched SetRowcount statements. So my question what if I forgot to add "Set RowCount 0" to my opening "Set RowCount N" statement. Is it neccessary ? Will it affect the executions of rest of the SPs in my application ?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468764/top-versus-set-rowcount

Comment: It seems to affect child batches but be reset upon exiting from a quick test.

Comment: @Martin Can you clear me on "but be reset upon exiting from a quick test" ?

Comment: There should probably be a comma before the `from a quick test` bit to show that it relates to `it seems` and not to `upon exiting`, but Martin has spared a keystroke or missed the key or otherwise neglected to add the necessary punctuation. :) So I think the actual sense of the sentence is: "From a quick test, the `SET ROWCOUNT` statement seems to Martin to affect child batches but be reset upon exiting *[from the stored procedure]*."

Comment: @Andriy - Whoops there was something of a punctuation deficiency in that sentence! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to the [accepted answer in the question linked to in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468764/top-versus-set-rowcount/468781#468781) as far as I can see the scope rules for this are exactly the same as those for `#temp` table visibility. It propagates to child batches but when the batch exits it gets reset to the previous value.

```
CREATE PROC #bar
AS
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM sys.objects')
GO

CREATE PROC #foo
AS
SET ROWCOUNT 1

EXEC #bar
GO

SET ROWCOUNT 4
EXEC #foo /*Returns 2 resultsets with 1 row*/
EXEC #bar /*Returns 2 resultsets with 4 rows*/

DROP PROC #foo
DROP PROC #bar
```