# Difference between top clause and set rocount

Tags: sybase

What is the difference between top clause and set rowcount  ..I am doing performance tuning for the stored procedure ...Which one is advisable for selecting top 1 record in procedure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468764/top-versus-set-rowcount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**top** and **set rowcount** are very similar, but **top** has a few restrictions and limitations that **set rowcount** does not.

From the Sybase [Reference Manual: Commands](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X35229.htm)

> top unsigned_integer
>   is used with select...into statements to limit the number of rows inserted in the target table. **This is different from set rowcount, which is ignored during a select...into.**
>
> •When used with delete, update, or in a view, you cannot specify ordering. If there is an implied order on the table from a clustered index, that order applies; otherwise, the results are unpredictable, as they can be in any order.
>
> •When used with cursors, top n limits the overall size of the result set. Specifying set cursor rowcount limits the results of a single fetch.
>
> •When a view definition contains select top n and a query with a where clause uses it, the results may be inconsistent.